# Load JDBC Driver without name from external JAR

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, jar

I want the user to decide what database to use. He should just provide the connector JAR file and the database URL.

The problem is, that I don't know the class name of the driver.

Is it possible to load the JAR using a `URLClassLoader` and register the driver without knowing the name. Until now, I only found solutions where the driver name is known.

I also tried to add a directory relative to the classpath of my exported JAR file (using maven assembly plugin) but it did not work.

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Class-Path>libs/*</Class-Path>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All JDBC 4 and higher compliant drivers contain a service definition file for use with `java.util.ServiceLoader`. If your application has the driver on the initial class path, you don't need to do anything, as `java.sql.DriverManager` will automatically load these drivers.

If the driver is on a secondary class path (eg in a web application context, or a manually initialized class loader), then you will need to manually load the driver to get it registered. In that case it should be possible to use `ServiceLoader` yourself to enumerate all available drivers on the class path of that context.

This can be done with [`ServiceLoader.load​(Class<S> service)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load(java.lang.Class)) or [`ServiceLoader.load​(Class<S> service, ClassLoader loader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load(java.lang.Class,java.lang.ClassLoader)). You can then iterate (or stream) instances of the available drivers (which will automatically register them with `DriverManager`).

Eg

```
ServiceLoader<Driver> drivers = ServiceLoader.load(java.sql.Driver.class, yourClassLoader);
for (Driver driver : drivers) {
    System.out.println(driver.getClass().getName());
}
```

The only thing you will need to know is the correct JDBC url to connect.

Please take into account that this can cause a memory leak if your class loader has a short lifetime: you will need to explicitly deregister the driver to avoid such a leak.

Comment: I will test it.

Comment: @dan1st Java 10 introduced the keyword `var` which allows you to not specify the type of a variable if it can be derived from the context. The compiler will infer it for you. But I will edit for clarity.

Comment: @dan1st The `var` is new syntax in Java 10 to implicitly ask the compiler to infer the class of that object-reference variable. See [JEP 286](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

Comment: I am using Java 8 but ok

Comment: @dan1st Unfortunately, so do I in my daily work. I have replaced var with the actual types.